# Not showing dataSetColors:overridden when categoryAxesSettings has minPeriod seconds

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm having a problem with amCharts stock charts: I need colours of lines to be changed by the dataset.

What I have done is:
see this-> https://codepen.io/make_it_curry/pen/VxLPGZ
So in the above-stated code, everything is working fine as desired. But as soon as I change:

```
"categoryAxesSettings": { "minPeriod": "ss" },
```

Colour goes default and it is overridden.

what I get is
https://codepen.io/make_it_curry/pen/WJvRKO;

Please Help!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not quite due to `minPeriod`. Stock charts don't support using `lineColorField` or any of the `*Field` properties out of the box due to its [data grouping functionality](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/). When you set the smaller period, the chart simply grouped your data, removing your `lineColorField` data.

In order to have the stock chart consistenly recognize the `*Field` information in your data, you have to disable the data grouping functionality by setting [`maxSeries: 0`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#maxSeries) in your `categoryAxesSettings`. Note that this will impact performance as the stock chart uses this functionality to handle larger datasets.

Here's an [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/59ce90df7336c1c55e98417e7e27d717/?editors=0010) with the `maxSeries` setting applied.